# Core MVC MapRoute Template & RequestDelegate Not Working

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

In .Net Core MVC 2.2 I'm trying to use the overload for MapRoute that takes a **String** for the template and a **RequestDelegate** for the handler. For some reason, my catch-all constraint to test this overload isn't working (the default route that comes after is invoked). What am I doing wrong? I'm even trying to throw an error in the handler but it never gets called. My code is as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(delegate (IRouteBuilder routes)
{                
    routes.MapRoute(
        template: "{**url}", //catch-all route
        handler: delegate (HttpContext Context){
            throw new Exception("test"); //throw an error to know for sure we make it here
            return new Task(()=>Context.Response.Redirect("https://www.microsoft.com"));
        });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

What this overload looks like on my screen:

[image]

Comment: Where is that overload coming from? I don't see it on `IRouteBuilder`. It doesn't really matter, as what you're trying to do isn't supported. What's the overall goal here?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I added a screenshot of the overload to the question. I'm curious to know if I can add some of my own custom route logic using this overload.

Comment: @KirkLarkin are you using Core 2.2? How do you know it's not supported?